# Expresión en español para "cerebro convertido en yogur"

Tags: traducción, modismos, solicitud-de-modismo

Acabo de ver [esta pregunta](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/416113) en las HNQ:

> In Hindi, there is an idiom "दिमाग का दही हो गया" (dimaag ka dahi ho
>   gaya) which literally translates to "brain turned into yogurt". This
>   is used when you're mentally exhausted and unable to think with your
>   usual speed/clarity. Example situations:
>
> - A student studying for a few hours.
> - A person bored by listening to speeches all day, even though they weren't paying much attention.
>
> Is there an English equivalent of this idiom?

Automáticamente me he acordado de una prima mía, que en situaciones similares usa la expresión "**tengo el cerebro hecho croqueta**" refiriéndose a la masa interior de las croquetas. El caso es que nunca he sabido si esa expresión se la ha inventado ella, o si la ha oído en alguna parte, o si es común en alguna parte de España, dado que solo se la he oído a ella. Por supuesto, no encuentro casos ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA, pero es que ni siquiera en Google encuentro resultados de búsqueda, lo que me induce a pensar que es una creación suya.

Así que pregunto: ¿existe algún modismo similar usado en español para expresar esa misma idea?

Comment: No es específico del cerebro pero lo habitual es decir "hecho puré" o "hecho papilla"

Comment: Seems rather a lovely idiom. I shall try to introduce it into English per haps you can try the same in Spain?

Comment: @mdewey if you mean the "croqueta" expression, I already use it whenever I can, as I liked it a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo creo que se puede usar la expresión **"tener la cabeza hecha un bombo"**. Tal y como yo la uso, sirve para todos para los casos que propones, aunque además también se puede usar para decir que te duele la cabeza.

También se me ocurren:

- "**Estar rayado**", aunque quizás sea mucho más genérica.
- Decir que alguien te está "**rompiendo la cabeza**". No se adapta exactamente a lo que pides, pero sirve para incidir en la causa (por culpa de otra persona).

Comment: Curioso. En Colombia "estar rayado" suena como a estar un poquito mal de la cabeza (enloquecer un poco).

Comment: Sí, aquí yo creo que también puede tener esa connotación, por eso puse que es una expresión muy genérica. Puede ser: estar harto de algo, estar un poco loco, estar exhausto mentalmente, estar preocupado, estar triste... Muchas posibilidades, depende del contexto.

Comment: Ah entiendo, no sabía que tenía varios significados.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me suena tener el [cerebro quemado](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/tengo-el-cerebro-quemado.1497446/):

> Esta expresión se refiere al cansancio mental producido por el exceso de estudio o trabajo mental.